# How to write a specific column from Pandas DataFrame to Excel without overwriting other columns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have an Excel input file in which one column is empty in the beginning. Then, based on the rest of the input, I am calculating `d_eff`, and I want it back in the same input file. Because there are formulas in other columns, I don't want to overwrite those.

So as an example, this is the file at the start:

| d_eff | d1 | d2 | check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 | d_eff = d1+d2? |
|  | 5 | 6 | d_eff = d1+d2? |

and then I'd like to have d_eff filled in by my script, without the formula in the `check` column being overwritten.

I am working with Pandas, so the input file is in a DataFrame `df`.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.d_eff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

But in this case, it places `d_eff` on Sheet11 instead of Sheet1.

How can I place `d_eff` in the Excel file on the excisting location, without overwriting the formulas in the other columns?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, consider editing the example so it will be more readable.

Comment: Better like this?

Comment: Makes a world of difference! While waiting for an answer, please, take a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

once you assign workbook name and sheet_name to your writer object. It should be able to append the data to existing sheet without overwriting others.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    df.d_eff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=0, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this, now it doesn't overwrite all columns, but just the first one. However, I want to have ```d_eff``` as either the last column, or as one that I pre-assign as d_eff.

Comment: what would be the position of your last column, Could you paste your expected result ?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you'd like me to paste. I thought pandas worked without specifying e.g. the amount of columns. So just the name d_eff would be enough? I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you can write it to specific column by setting 'startcol' parameter in the pd.to_excel() function. I have updated startcol = 0 which would write to column A in excel.